# How does Google Maps knows where I am?

Tags: google-maps, ip

I'm building a log system that records in a database the visitor ip and get some info of it from this api http://ip-api.com/json/{ip}, but the api give me my city and coordenates wrong, I thought I had nothing to do, that it was a thing of the ISP, but then I enter in Google Maps and it knows exactly where I am in the map.
From where is GMaps getting this info?

pdt: I have deactivated location in chrome for gmaps, it still kowns where I am.

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps uses [Location API.](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/location.html)